# Why did the use of "hello" temporarily plummet in the United States?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, greetings

According to [Google Books Ngram View](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hello%3Aeng_gb_2012%2CHello%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHello%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHello%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0), the appearance of the word "Hello" in its U.S. corpus dropped by more than 50% from the early 1940s to the 1960s before returning to its earlier level in the 1990s. No such decline appeared in the Great British corpus.

[image: Graph illustrating the described phenomenon]

As someone who lived through the second half of this period, I am baffled by the change in usage, which I hadn't noticed. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: If you run [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hello%3Aeng_us_2012%2CHi%3Aeng_us_2012&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CHello%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BHello%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhello%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHELLO%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CHi%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhi%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHi%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHI%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) you'll see that the use of the word "Hi" increases as "Hello" declines. Is this significant? I don't know.

Comment: I appreciated the vote, however I felt it would be best if I deleted my answer, since a double-check came out differently. I hope someone who is more familiar with the NGrams can straighten it out for us. This is what I got the second time and I don't know why: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hello%3Aeng_us_2012%2CHi%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHello%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHi%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: These are written texts, not the use of the word in speech.  Many of them (hello or hi) are "false positives," e.g., consider hi-fi. Many others are likely to be dialog in fiction.